# Bash redirecting stdio to named pipes

Tags: bash, asynchronous, pipe, named-pipes

I have a couple of processes running asynchronously and each takes input from a fifo and trhows it's output to another fifo. I want to read those asynchronously. The problem is that I can't seem to get the output before the fifo has closed. Here is an example

```
#!/bin/bash -x

rm -rf /tmp/fifo[123].{in,out}
for i in $(seq 1 3) ; do
    mkfifo /tmp/fifo$i.in
    mkfifo /tmp/fifo$i.out
done

fin1=/tmp/fifo1.in
fout1=/tmp/fifo1.out

fin2=/tmp/fifo2.in
fout2=/tmp/fifo2.out

fin3=/tmp/fifo3.in
fout3=/tmp/fifo3.out

(echo "Proc 1"; while read var; do echo "proc1: " $var; done) < $fin1 > $fout1 &
(echo "Proc 2"; while read var; do echo "proc2: " $var; done) < $fin2 > $fout2 &
(echo "Proc 3"; while read var; do echo "proc3: " $var; done) < $fin3 > $fout3 &

# Get some of the output
cat $fout1 >> /tmp/test.before
cat $fout2 >> /tmp/test.before
cat $fout3 >> /tmp/test.before

# Generate more output
echo "Do you copy proc 1" > $fin1
echo "Do you copy proc 1" > $fin2
echo "Do you copy proc 1" > $fin3

# Get the rest of the output
cat $fout1 >> /tmp/test.after
cat $fout2 >> /tmp/test.after
cat $fout3 >> /tmp/test.after

# Show the results
echo "Before input:"
cat /tmp/test.before

echo "After input:"
cat /tmp/test.after
```

Which results in

```
$ ./test.sh
+ rm -rf '/tmp/fifo[123].in' '/tmp/fifo[123].out'
++ seq 1 3
+ for i in '$(seq 1 3)'
+ mkfifo /tmp/fifo1.in
+ mkfifo /tmp/fifo1.out
+ for i in '$(seq 1 3)'
+ mkfifo /tmp/fifo2.in
+ mkfifo /tmp/fifo2.out
+ for i in '$(seq 1 3)'
+ mkfifo /tmp/fifo3.in
+ mkfifo /tmp/fifo3.out
+ fin1=/tmp/fifo1.in
+ fout1=/tmp/fifo1.out
+ fin2=/tmp/fifo2.in
+ fout2=/tmp/fifo2.out
+ fin3=/tmp/fifo3.in
+ fout3=/tmp/fifo3.out
+ cat /tmp/fifo1.out
```

How can I get asynchronous communication like that? I would like to avoid coprocesses because I dont know in advance how many asynchronous processes I will need and things will get messy.

Comment: For starters, you don't seem to be writing anything to `$fin1` before calling `cat $fout1`, so your script blocks there waiting for anything to appear in `$fout1`.

Comment: yeah that's the point, i want to read the string "Proc1" beore writing to `$fin`

Comment: @fakedrake, why do you expect the backgrounded loops to have finished writing before your main process gets to the point where it's reading from the `$fout` files? You're backgrounding the whole subshell, not just the read loop, so the first `echo` is running asynchronously too. If you want any kind of timing guarantees, you'll need to do some locking to provide them yourself.

Comment: That said -- if you wanted this to be even moderately efficient, you'd be better off implementing it in a language with access to the `select()` call or its more recent equivalents. Sure, you're not using the `coproc` keyword, but you basically *are* using coprocesses as it is.

Comment: Hmm, my specific casei is that I have many instances netcat listening on a couple of ports. When someone sends a request to a port I want to throw to netcat's stdin a specific sring different for each instance. Is there no way to do that in bash?

Comment: It's certainly _possible_ in bash, just wildly inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following line

```
for x in $fout1 $fout2 $fout3; do printf "" > $x & done
```

immediately before you start the three subprocesses seems to break the deadlock. I'm not entirely sure why. Replacing the empty string with some text produces that text in `test.before`, so I suspect that the entire subshell, not just the enclosed `read`, blocks on the I/O redirections.

Comment: That is interesting but didn't quite cut it. It doesnt block but I needed the first part of the output on the .before file.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you put stdout and stderr redirections outside subshell:

```
(echo "Proc 1"; while read var; do echo "proc1: " $var; done) < $fin1 > $fout1 &
(echo "Proc 2"; while read var; do echo "proc2: " $var; done) < $fin2 > $fout2 &
(echo "Proc 3"; while read var; do echo "proc3: " $var; done) < $fin3 > $fout3 &
```

IMHO Should became:

```
(echo "Proc 1" > $fout1; while read var; do echo "proc1: " $var; done < $fin1 >> $fout1) &
(echo "Proc 2" > $fout2; while read var; do echo "proc2: " $var; done < $fin2 >> $fout2) &
(echo "Proc 3" > $fout3; while read var; do echo "proc3: " $var; done < $fin3 >> $fout3) &
                                                                           look here ^^^^^
```

So all the processes, including redirections, are in a subshell that is forked from the main process, and the main script will not block on the first while cycle.

Comment: In the original, the output of the `echo` went to `$fout1` et al. as well. Moving the redirections inside the subshell requires adding a redirection to `echo`.